# Split the Table into multiple excel files using ssis

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

There is a table with 5000 records ,I need to split it into 10 excel files with names 
Jan_DEpt_Records.xlsx,Feb_Deptname_Records.xlsx etc.How to achieve this with ssis.

Here "Dept" part of the excel name would come from the source table dept column.

It has been understood the use of for each loop and dataflow task inside foreachloop.

Answer (score 1):

You should use conditional splits and in that you can right the cases for the number of records and than pass it to your excels just replace derived columns with the sample excel.insert indentity column on basis of that you can differentiate  :[image]

Comment: Thanks Rahuk,but how would i get the excel sheet with name.The part of the name has to be derived from one of the tables column